# Has anyone got the Oscurart tools Add on to work in Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, add-on, object-mode

I've enabled the Oscurart tools add on through Preferences and can see/right click to access the list of its functions/options. Its "Remove modifiers" function works, but I can't seem to get the "distribute objects" functionality to make any changes whatsoever to a selection of multiple objects to get them to align along a selected axis as defined in its "distribute Objects" option.
[image]
[image]

To repro:
Turn Oscurart on in Add on via Preferences.
Create 3 simple cubes -- each as separate objects.
Select them all while in Object mode.
Then choose the Distribute objects option in Oscurart.
I expect the 3 cubes to align to the selected axis in the Distribute Objects dialog box, but nothing seems to be happening.

Nothing I change in the axis options does anything to align/distribute the selected objects along the chosen axis's 
(reminder this is in Blender v2.8)

Is there a problem with the add on? Thanks!

[image: Viewport]

Comment: Hello. The distribution still works in 2.8. Could you please attach a screenshot of your 3D viewport, with the cubes you need to distribute? Oscurart tools is kinda sensitive about selecting objects the right way.

Comment: Added my screen (hope that's what you wanted). I have not even got it to work in a clean project, with just 3 simple cubes duplicated from the default that were moved around a bit to get them all out of alignment.  What is the "sensitivity" about selection that you mention?  What I did was in Object mode to simply select either one after another in a row, and in another test, the 2 end ones first then the one in the center, but nothing seems to work.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: didn't know how to find the oscurant tool, found out here I had to right click

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the origin point of each of the objects is different. Oscurart Tools won't work if all of the objects have the same origin in space. So before distributing, set each object's origin to the geometry and then try it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use "Distribute Objects" from the [search menu](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/templates/operator_search.html):

[image: distribute objects search results]

Comment: Add a screenshot as now it looks like a comment.

Comment: Consider either editing you answer to make it longer, or adding a comment. This answer is too short.

Comment: Doesn't work in Blender 2.90.1. I have to use the "right-click" *Object Context Menu* to access Oscurart.