# Move object using coordinates from other objects

Tags: transforms

Is it possible to move an object using coordinates from other objects?

Example (see screenshot): Is it easily possible to move the blue cube in x-direction using the distance from the upper right corner of the green cube and the upper right corner of the right cube?

I currently measure the distance with snapping and add the number manually to the x-position of the blue cube in the location panel.

[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

Comment: there are many "Object Constraint" where a change in one object (x,y,z location, x,y,z scale, x,y,z rotation, etc) can effect an assigned objects position, rotation, scale, etc.   many tutorials, like the following google search:
https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+object+constraints+tutorial

Comment: There is Oscurart tools https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156696/has-anyone-got-the-oscurart-tools-add-on-to-work-in-blender-2-8 which you can run with only distribution by one axis (X in that case). Meanwhile, standard snapping has multiple points mode (press A with the active tool)

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/203504/35559) should work for you. Working as described there, start by snapping the 3D cursor to the top-right vertex of the green cube. That is your relative 'From' point. Now GX the blue cube until the 'From' point snaps to the top-right of the red cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to have a look at this addon. It lets you do all kinds of things that are usually very simple in more CAD based platforms
https://github.com/s-leger/blender_cad_transforms

Comment: The CAD Transform addon is the solution. The function, I was looking for, is called: Soft Constraints. This is an amazing tool! I highly recommend to give it a try and support the developer.

Comment: yeah!! Its super slick!